# add subtitle to sidebar beamer

Tags: beamer

In the sidebar theme from beamer, how can one replace the author with the subtitle? I found the [.sty file for sidebar](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemesidebar.sty), and another posts describes removing the author (and title) from the sidebar, and I know the subtitle can be inserted using `\insertsubtitle`, but I can't figure out how to combine both these insights.

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}
\title{Supply and Demand}
\subtitle{Econ 101}
\author{Dr. Economist}
\institute{College of Dreams}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item This is some text.
    \item Some more text. 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use optional argument to author:`\author[short here]{Dr.\ Economist}`

Comment: @Sigur how exactly does this answer the question

Comment: It doesn't. But it is workaround. You want to replace author by subtitle. So you can write the subtitle as optional argument so author will be changed.

Comment: @Sigur indeed but this marks it harder to compile with pandoc when author in yaml doesn't have that option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme{sidebar}
\let\insertshortauthor\insertshortsubtitle

\title{Supply and Demand}
\subtitle{Econ 101}
\author{Dr. Economist}
\institute{College of Dreams}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item This is some text.
  \item Some more text. 
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}
\title{Supply and Demand}
\subtitle{Econ 101}
\author{Dr. Economist}
\institute{College of Dreams}
\date{}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}
{
  \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
  \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt%
  {\usebeamerfont{title in sidebar}%
    \vskip1.5em%
    \hskip3pt%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{title in sidebar}%
    \insertshorttitle[width=\beamer@tempdim,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
    \vskip1.25em%
  }%
  {%
    \hskip3pt%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{author in sidebar}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in sidebar}%
%    \insertshortauthor[width=\beamer@tempdim,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
    \insertshortsubtitle[width=\beamer@tempdim,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
    \vskip1.25em%
  }%
  \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
  \vfill
  \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
  \else%
    \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
    \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
    \vskip2pt%
  \fi%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item This is some text.
    \item Some more text. 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]