# Seeking Beamer Template Similar to Presentation Below

Tags: beamer, templates, legend

I'm a really big fan of this presentation style

https://www.archer.ac.uk/training/course-material/2014/04/PMMP_UCL/Slides/castep_1.pdf

and I'm wondering if anyone has come across the sort of clickable+expanding/minimizing legend used on the left hand side of each slide. I haven't been able to find on the TeX exchange so far this exact kind of legend type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the best solution but you can use `\useoutertheme[hideothersubsections,left]{sidebar}` to hide the subsections of not selected subsections and use:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
}
```

to make the table of content clickable.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\useoutertheme[hideothersubsections,left]{sidebar} %hides the subsetions of not selected sections

\usepackage{color}   
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
}
\title{Amazing Presentation}
\author{By Me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]{}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain, allowframebreaks]
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{A subsection}\begin{frame}{}\end{frame}
\subsection{Another subsection}\begin{frame}{}\end{frame}
\subsection{So many subsections}\begin{frame}{}\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Even more subsections!}\begin{frame}{}\end{frame}
\subsubsection{Subsubsections are possible as well}\begin{frame}{}\end{frame}
\subsubsection{Amazing!}\begin{frame}{}\end{frame}
\subsection{The subsections are even clickable}\begin{frame}{}\end{frame}
\subsection{I think you get the point}\begin{frame}{}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Presentation with legend]

[image: Presentation with legend 2]

If you want to, you can [customize the sidebar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352825/36296)

I got the idea of using frames this way from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391036/194523).

Comment: Thank you for your help, earthwalker31 :)